# Contract Testing - Spring Boot Microservices with external SOAP/REST downstream services

Tags: spring-boot, pact, spring-cloud-contract, contract

We have a set of microservices communicating with each other and some external downstream services. Spring Cloud Contract is used for integration tests to check the service interfaces. I'm able to test the contracts for communication between the microservices.

I'd like to know how to write the contract tests for a producer which

- doesn't provide any contracts (cannot access source code)
- SOAP-based

Can I impose the contracts from the consumer itself?

Couldn't find the SCC documentation helpful in this regard. Any helpful pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at tools like pact.io?

Comment: @Matthew - yes, I did. Couldn't find solution using Pact as well.

Comment: So sorry Amer. I responded to this on mobile and didn't see the tags. It also looked like the question has changed since I asked it so my response looks/is irrelevant. Marcin has done a fine job answering though 

Answer (score 1):

If it's SOAP based then it's a standard XML based communication. You can generate XML based contracts (an example is here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#contract-dsl-xml ). Now as for the one where you don't have access to source code, what you can is the following:

- You can create a test that will go via a proxy (e.g. WireMock proxy) to the real application and that way you will store that communication in a form of stubs (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyHG-VOzPZg), you can also check the code (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/the-legacy-app/tree/master/stubs_with_proxy). The problem here is that the producer might not be idempotent or may require a lot of concrete setup on the input to get proper response (e.g. a precisely defined date).
- You can create contracts on the consumer side, tell stubrunner where they lay (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#features-stub-runner-stubs-protocol) and turn the `generateStubs` feature (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#features-stub-runner-generate-stubs-at-runtime), example of code (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/consumer_with_latest_2_2_features/src/test/java/com/example/GenerateStubsTest.java). The problem here is that as a consumer you can write whatever you want and it might not have anything to do with reality. On the other hand you already have the contracts that you could upload to the producer side with a request that they implement their part one day.

It's up to you to decide which one you prefer, bearing in mind that each of the solutions might have its issues.

As for Pact, Pact follows the second approach since it's the consumer that defines how the interaction should look like. That again might have nothing to do with reality.